# laravel get most related post by tag

Tags: laravel

I have a  relationship between post and tag in post show page I'm trying to display post related to the post show content but excluding the main show content it's not working and I'm not getting error.

```php
class PostShow extends Component
{
    public $post;
    public $body;
    public $slug;
    public $comment;

    public function mount(Post $post) {
        $this->post = $post;
    }

    protected $rules = [
        'comment' => 'string|required|min:3|max:5000',
    ];

    protected $listeners = [
        'commentWasAdded'
    ];

    public function commentWasAdded() {
        $this->post->refresh();
    }

    public function render() {
        $post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

        $related = Post::whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($post) {
            return $q->whereIn('name', $post->tags->pluck('name')); 
        })
        ->where('id', '!=', $post->id) // So you won't fetch same post
        ->get();

        return view('livewire.post-show',[
            'related' => $related,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the error say??

Comment: `$slug` is undefined, btw

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.